# Checkers game with java questions and concerns

Tags: java

Firstly, I am very new to programming in general and I was making a checkers program.

1. How would I approach and implement the interface for the checker pieces and make them "Sync" with the 2d array I have representing the board.
2. How would my method for moving or skipping be done? this also includes the rule that allows you to double skip if the circumstance allows.
3. Is it correct to try and assemble this program using mostly methods? I was thinking that I would make a method for all functions I need and perform them in the proper sequence in my main and have them in a loop. Does this make sense?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.  Your question is much too broad to be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

1. You usually have an event loop: receive input, update the internal state (including the computer's move), display the results, wait for input,.. You can choose whatever method of display. Start with the most trivial for now, such as printing the board using `System.out.print`. You will change things later, when you have more important bits figured out.
2. Search the web. There's a number of methods to approach games with full information, read about game trees. Check Wikipedia, [for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Core_idea).
3. Yes. Think about your program as of a function / method computing the next state, given inputs. Consider a [top-down approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design#Software_development) and implement more and more details. Start with defining your data structures, such as the board, and the move-lookup tree nodes.

In general, find a good programming introduction book, and keep reading it. If you're audacious and want to level up quickly despite being constantly puzzled, [try SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Answer (score 1):

use the [mvc mini arhcitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - changes in the model (your 2d array) will result in an update call to your view so you can update the display.